# Delete records from CTE in small batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to delete old records from a table that is being written recently. My problem is that when an other process is trying to read or write into the table my delete statement fails with deadlock.
It's part of a big stored procedure which starts with a `Transaction isolation level read uncommitted` and `deadlockpriority low`.

How can I transform this cte and delete statement to delete records partially? For example a while would be perfect if I could select the count of the records in the cte (x) that run the delete statement for x/500 records.

```
  ;with chargesToDelete(id, ciid) as (
        select c.id, ci.Id from @chargeids c
        left join xxx.dbo.chargeitems ci on ci.Charge_Id = c.id
        where ci.id is null
    )
    delete from xxx.dbo.charges
        where Id in (select id from chargesToDelete);
```

Comment: Is this a "Deleting in Batches" question?  Aaron Bertrand has blogged about this here: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop with session variable `@@ROWCOUNT` with a `TOP N` on your `DELETE`.

```
SELECT 1 -- Forces @@ROWCOUNT = 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN

    delete TOP (500) I from 
        xxx.dbo.charges AS I
    where 
        exists (
            select 
                'to delete' 
            from 
                @chargeids c
                left join xxx.dbo.chargeitems ci on ci.Charge_Id = c.id
            where 
                ci.id is null AND
                c.id = I.Id)

END
```

If you don't want to use a sentinel `SELECT` (which will return results to the client, if any), you can use a variable.

```
DECLARE @ForceStart BIT = 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 OR @ForceStart = 1
BEGIN

    SET @ForceStart = 0

    delete TOP (500) I from 
        xxx.dbo.charges AS I
    where 
        exists (
            select 
                'to delete' 
            from 
                @chargeids c
                left join xxx.dbo.chargeitems ci on ci.Charge_Id = c.id
            where 
                ci.id is null AND
                c.id = I.Id)

END
```

If your subquery takes long to process, you might want to create a temporary table with the IDs to delete and join with it on the loop.

As a side note, if you are checking the not existance of records on `xxx.dbo.chargeitems`, doing a `NOT EXISTS` will be faster than a `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL`.

---

**Edit**: using a temporary table to hold the IDs:

```
-- Create temporary table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChargesToDelete') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ChargesToDelete

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.id
INTO
    #ChargesToDelete
from 
    @chargeids c
    left join xxx.dbo.chargeitems ci on ci.Charge_Id = c.id
where 
    ci.id is null

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_ChargesToDelete ON #ChargesToDelete (id)


-- Delete rows in batches
SELECT 1 -- Forces @@ROWCOUNT = 1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN

    delete TOP (500) I from 
        xxx.dbo.charges AS I
    where 
        exists (select 'to delete' from #ChargesToDelete AS C where c.id = I.Id)

END
```

Comment: Altough the solution doesn't use the CTE it seems that this does the delete without locking the whole table.

Comment: A deadlock was thrown again during the third run. How can I run this delete to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: @Perrier Make sure that this operation isn't inside a transaction, or do an explicit begin transaction and commit after each delete (inside the loop). You will also have to check if the deadlock is against another procedure or scripts running against these same tables.

Comment: The SP starts with a try-catch block in order to handle errors correctly. But try doesn't start a transaction as far as I know.

Comment: @Perrier create a temporary table with the IDs you need to delete, then use this table to join against `charges` (instead of joining each time with `chargeitems`). That should ease the shared locking times. Also make sure you dont have locking hints (like `WITH(UPDLOCK)`) on another parts of your SP.

Comment: This temptable was the chargesToDelete CTE for. You mean write them into a table in the database?

Comment: @Perrier yes, don't use CTE as it will have to calculate the IDs to delete each time. I've added an example of holding the IDs to delete on a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Dropping CTE, and using the temp table with the while loop solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
declare @deleted table (id int)
declare @amountToDelete int = 2

delete from @deleted
    delete top (@amountToDelete) from xxx.dbo.charges
    output deleted.* into @deleted
    where not exists(select 1 from xxx.dbo.chargeitems
                     where charge_id = xxx.dbo.charges.id)

while (select count(*) from @deleted) = @amountToDelete
begin
    delete from @deleted
    delete top (@amountToDelete) from xxx.dbo.charges
    output deleted.* into @deleted
    where not exists(select 1 from xxx.dbo.chargeitems
                     where charge_id = xxx.dbo.charges.id)
end
```

`@amountToDelete` means the size of batch of record to delete at one time. The other variable, of type `table`, holds deleted `id`s at one run of a loop. Condition to stop the loop is that there were deleted fewer records than there supposed to be deleted (which means that there were last records to delete and they has been deleted), which corresponds to this condition:

```
while (select count(*) from @deleted) = @amountToDelete
```

First delete is performed before (outside) the loop. If all recrods are deleted at first, code won't go into the loop.